# Is my diet affecting my skin?

Tags: acne

So I am at my wits end with acne. I've got rid of **all** of the spots (like the physical spots that most people would want to pop) with the help of Lymecycline (a skin antibiotic) that the doctor gave me and a spot gel she gave me, but I still have red, inflamed skin. I change my pillowcase every night on a rotor, I stopped drinking milk, I'm doing **every single thing** I have read online and been told because I am incredibly, incredibly angry now at this.

I don't want to come across as a picky eater, but I really find it quite hard to eat a lot of foods, primarily vegetables like peas and green beans, because I can't stand how they feel in your mouth. I also find the act of eating quite disgusting and I really hate doing it so it's quite hard for me to incorporate new foods into my diet, but I have been trying to incorporate sweet potatoes because apparently they help acne.

This is what I eat:

- Breakfast. I always have a bowl of pasta with tuna in. I wanted to be able to have carbohydrates to give me energy, but at the same time, I wanted to fight acne. Tuna apparently is good for acne.
- Lunch. Some days I don't eat lunch because I really just, I just hate eating. But, when I do, I have plain cous cous and nothing else, every single day.
- Tea. I live in England and tend to have those kinds of 'hearty' meals that are common like Sheperds Pie, Cottage Pie, meat, stuff like that. Dumplings. Curry. Those kinds of things. Often in these recipes you include carrots or parsnips but I leave these out because I don't like how they feel in your mouth.

So that's what I'm eating. I have no idea if my diet is what's giving me the inflamed skin so I have turned to Health SE for answers. I told my doctor I stopped drinking milk because it was bad for acne but she said my acne is completely hormonal and I should put milk back in because I used to have a warm glass of milk before I went to bed.

I have taken a picture of the problem so you can see it. Hang on, it's uploading.

[image: Acne]

Okay so as we can see from the image I've got 3 spots at the minute, but to be honest they'll probably go down pretty fast. The main focus isn't those - it is the inflamed, red skin.

- Why do I have this red skin?
- What can I do to get rid of it?

I promise I will do whatever I'm told.

Comment: I promise I will do whatever I'm told.
^ Find a proper Doctor/Nutritionist/Dermatologist and take your questions there. Health.Se is not meant for personal matters.

Comment: In particular, your dermatologist can tell you if the inflammation is the result of some or all of the things you've read about online.

Comment: You need a dermatologist for this inflammation.  They may recommend an allergist if you're having cutaneous manifestations when you eat certain foods.  But if this is inflammatory acne, a dermatologist should see it.  Also, you need to balance your diet - there are skin manifestations of vitamin/mineral deficiencies too!  You're eating almost no fruits or vegetables which, sorry, your body needs.  There are all sorts of ways to make fruits and vegetables palatable such as blenders, sauces...

Answer (score 1):

Your doctor is probably right about it being a hormonal imbalance, but why do you have a hormonal imbalance?  That would be a great question for you to ask your doctor.  Hormonal imbalances can be caused because of a food sensitivity.  Dairy, wheat and soy are the big ones, but it may be one, two, or all three of them. Or it could be something unrelated to food.  Everyone is individualized.  The following site helped me to figure out what worked for me, it is a great resource for figuring out your individual needs. 
https://www.acneeinstein.com/. This site is very detailed and explains the problem of acne in understandable language.  As well as multiple causes.  When cutting something out of your diet you also need to be sure you have completely cut it out.  Milk includes butter, and any processed foods with milk, so no milk chocolate and even most dark chocolates have milk.  However, everybody is individualized and this may not be the case for you.  Also, to make the question more appropriate for the site you could ask... Does diet affect skin? Then make the more detailed portion a bit more generalized.